# Storing historical prices in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have an application where I need to store historical prices for a product 
maximum of 50 last price changes.

product ID - 
and then 
Date+Time / Decimal price for each price change

I am thinking of using MongoDB for that. Is that a good fit ? and what is the structure you would use for such an app ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TBH, any one of a whole number of DBs would be a good fit, MongoDB included. As to whether it makes MongoDB the best solution for you, that's impossible to answer as "best" is subjective.

In Mongo, I think a good way to store it would be to have a product document, with the price history stored within the same document as the product.

e.g.

```
{
    "Code" : "Prod1",
    "Description" : "Product 1",
    "Price" : 10.99
    "PriceHistory" : [
    {
        "Date" : "20110121010203",
        "Price" : 11.99
    },
    {
        "Date" : "20101201000000",
        "Price" : 13.49
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks that confirms what I understood, can anyone paste an example using gpymongo to do a push for a new price to this structure ?

Comment: Since you need to store the latest 50 historical prices, if you do go with MongoDB, keep an eye on http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-991 - it is a ticket for implementing fixed size arrays. In your case, and in the example that @AdaTheDev provided, you would be able to easily keep the 50 newest historical prices.

Comment: If we want to upsert to this document for merging, because of embedded doc `PriceHistory`, upsert will fail. Is there a way to prevent that? Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45718580/customize-mgo-upsert-operation